# Как сделать контейнер имел max-width таким, чтобы левая часть была с отступом, а правая шла через весь экран

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы грузовик касался правой части экрана, но при этом, чтобы левая часть с текстом имела такой же отступ как и у header а, нужно сделать это без позиционирования грузовика, контейнер имеет max-width:1270px

Comment: Кодом, как же ещё)

Comment: А с чего вдруг такое условие - "без позиционирования"?

Comment: А если у меня ultrwide монитор, у меня далеко далеко справа я так понял грузовик будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь в цветах блоков разберётесь и ширину я уменьшил, что бы здесь отображалось корректно.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: gray;
  display: grid;
}
.container {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
.info {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.image-region {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="info">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <div class="image-region">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```